# How to create EdgeRDD in Graphx

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using spark 1.4.0 and graphx and I have my graph edges stored in file and I use the following lines of code
to store them in an RDD. I would like to use EdgeRDD instead of RDD[Edge[String]]

```
val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] = edge_file.map(line => {val x = line.split("\\s+")
Edge(x(0).toLong, x(1).toLong, " "); })
```

I tried this

```
val edgesRDD = EdgeRDD(edges)
```

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EdgeRDD.fromEdges(edges)` should do the trick.